# Linear Optimization With Two Variables, given starting Values

Tags: optimization

Let's suppose we are given the following inequalities:

```
3x + 7y <= 71
4x + 9y <= 21
    ...
```

and so on, in the above format. The coefficients and the value generated (71,21 ...) would be positive, and x and y would also be positive. The input would be inputted as follows:

```
3 7 71
4 3 18
  ...
```

and so on, in the above format.

We would also be given some starting values for x and y: x = 7, y = 9.

With this, we would be try to find the amount of change that we would need to get to fit x and y into the inequalities. In this case, we would find that the optimal (and only possible value) x and y would be x = 5, y = 1, which would require the next change to be 2 and 8, giving a final answer of 10 (2+8).

I have looked around to see how to do this efficiently/simply, but couldn't find anything without using colossal libraries that I can't use. Unfortunately, I'm not really sure how to do this optimally other than brute-force checking integer values.

To clarify, I can do this manually, but if there are 100 inequalities with large numbers, it gets tiresome, so I would need c++ code to do this.

I have looked into using simplex, but it seems overkill for something this simple, and I anyways can't use external libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by "amount of change"?  Is that the sum of absolute values of differences in $x$ and $y$ from their starting values?  A standard linear programming solver seems like a fine solution.

Comment: I think you got excellent advice on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75563262/781723.  It is not clear why you cannot use external libraries.  If you can't, then you can always re-implement the same algorithms they use, and that's up to you.  Requests for software recommendations are generally off-topic here.